Guys are robbing a big corp in beginning and escape through tunnels on motor bikes
My brother started watching this movie and then had to leave. He couldn't find it after and is pretty upset because he was interested in the movie. Those are all the details he could tell me. 
He said it looked like they were robbing the Twin Towers and the jumped on motor bikes and went flying through tunnels and sewers. Some guy almost caught one of the robbers but they all stopped and shot the guy. Can anybody help me find out what movie this is? 

(approximate?) year of release?  Country?  Language?

It is Welcome to the Punch, a British crime and revenge caper starring Mark Strong and James McAvoy. 
The initial scene you describe is essentially a flashback, happening some time before the main action. MaAvoy plays the policeman trying to catch a gang led by Strong and is badly injured in the chase sequence. This sets up the tense main action where McCoy's cop attempts to trap Strong's thief, but later has to cooperate with him.
Part of the initial chase is here.

@JamieMyers If this is the correct answer, don't forget to approve it (by clicking on the check mark next to it).
